# Xcode test : clean up code, even when stopped

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, swift5, xcuitest

I am running some xcode test (with XCTest/XCUITest).

I need some clean up to be performed at the end of each test, even when the test is stopped manually (via the square stop button in xcode).

Unfortunately in that case, the tearDownWithError is not called.

How can I write a piece of code that I am guaranteed will always run, even when the test is manually stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to override tearDown()? I think it will help

Comment: I did override tearDown, but it is not called when manually pressing "STOP".

Answer (score 0):

You most likely can't. The stop button basically sends `SIGKILL` to the running test suite. While you could maybe try installing a signal handler to intercept `SIGKILL` and do the cleanup, I expect this would be difficult to do reliably.

It would probably be more fruitful to focus your energy on re-designing the test suite to be resilient in the face of a missed cleanup. What exactly do you need to do in the clean up?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the clean up, I need to create an attachement.

Comment: How would you go about trying to install a signal handle to the testing class?

Comment: What do you mean by "create an attachment"?

Comment: I mean creating an XCTAttachement. Don’t worry too much about it though, it’s not relevant to my question.